# Is SearchLight Package using Connection Pools?

Tags: julia

`SearchLight` is a Julia package that builds the ORM (object-relational mapping) layer in `Genie` (a web development framework in Julia).

Right now, I am building a website backend and I decided to use SearchLight for data storing, because someone told me to do so with an ORM instead of "just" parsing SQL queries - sorry, I am so not a web developer and know basically nothing.

Unfortunately, SearchLight is (i) unbelievably badly documented (i.e. in most cases not at all) and (ii) missing important functionalities, like setting foreign keys in a DB table. I found several work-arounds, even if they are not pretty and kind of counter the ORM idea.

### Actual Question

**Does SearchLight use connection pools?**
The web service I'm building, gets a JSON, queries the database, gets the result and sends it back to the client. This might take several seconds and multiple clients doing a request should not "stand in line" and wait for other requests to finish. Will SearchLight do that? I.e. open several connections and use them when they're needed? (Or does it something else that leads to what I want?)